# Como eu desabilito a função clicar no css?

Tags: html, css, html5, css3

A tabela abaixo tem um `<li>` e dentro desse `<li>` tem o `<a>`. Gostaria de desabilitar o link com o css:

```
<li id="menu-item-6858" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom">
  <a href="#" tabindex="0" role="link">
    <span class="menu-item-text">
      <h4>CONHEÇA TAMBÉM</h4>
    </span>
  </a>
</li>
```

Comment: .disabled { cursor:default; pointer-events:none; text-decoration:none; color:black; }

Answer (score -1):

```
.desabilita {
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

Comment: .isDisabled {
  color: currentColor;
  cursor: not-allowed;
  opacity: 0.5;
  text-decoration: none;
}

Comment: Obrigado deu certo,,